# What exception to throw when checking arguments?

Tags: python

I'm defining a function in Python. It has two keyword arguments. Both can be given. If only one is given, I can find a sensible value for the other. However, it does not make sense to fill in neither of the arguments.

My implementation looks like this:

```
def my_fun(foo=None,bar=None):
    if foo is None:
        if bar is None:
            raise Error("My error")
        ... etc
```

What is the most standard error to throw? Is a `ValueError` the right choice?

Comment: I might be inclined to follow what other functions do when they get the wrong number of arguments, but it's up to you to decide and document what your specific functions do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common errors due to invalid arguments can be:

- ValueErorr -- when values are incorrect or outside a valid range,
  example: passing negative numbers to a square root function -- this might be suited for your case
- TypeError
  -- when parameters have the wrong type: passing string "0.2" instead of a float 0.2

Also when your both arguments are missing can be expressed in a more pythonic way as:

```
if foo is None and bar is None:
    raise ValueError("Expected at least one argument")
```

Please have a look at the builtin exceptions documentation for a wider range of exceptions and their meaning: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html